# Possible to combine two device specific WiFi networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, merge, tablet

Onboard my sailing boat I  have at least two devices that creates separate local WiFi's to transfer information to my tablet. Device 1 is a depth sounder that transfers the sonar image and device 2 is a radar that transfers the radar image.
My challenge is that my tablet (like all other tablets I know) only is capable of connecting to one WiFi at the time, so when I connect to the local WiFi generated by device 1) it disconnects from the local WiFi of device 2 hence losing the connection to one of them.

Does anyone have a solution on how I could merge these two local WiFi's into one (probably 3rd) WiFi so that I am able to access both device 1 and 2 at the same time (simultaneously) without having to switch between the two networks.

All help very much appreciated!

Comment: Different devices have different Wi-Fi related capabilities. That makes it hard for us to give you a solid answer unless we can look up the manuals for your exact devices to see exactly what they're capable of, with respect to Wi-Fi. Since you didn't give us the makes and models of your devices, so we can't look up their manuals and learn their capabilities. Please edit your Question to include the make and model# of both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Many Wi-Fi capable devices (not laptops or tablets or smartphones, but embedded devices like printers or security cameras…and I'm guessing also your maritime devices), when first taken out of the box, will publish their own Wi-Fi network just so you can join it from a laptop or smartphone and get it set up.

As part of the setup process you usually tell the device what your existing home Wi-Fi network name and password is, and the device then joins that existing network.

So if you don't already have a Wi-Fi AP (wireless router) on your sailboat, you should get one, set it up (even if it won't have access to the Internet), and then tell both of your other devices to join that existing network. Then you can have your tablet join your AP and it will be able to see both maritime devices on that network.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your help! What you describe in terms of the setting-up process for many devices like printers, that is very much like my situation eventhough I think that the own wifi network that device creates is the standard method to connect to the app on the phone/tablet, rather than a temporary connection method. 

One of the devices that I want to connect to: 
[link](https://store.vexilar.com/sonarphone-w-hs-transducer-phone-not-included.html)

It seems that it is not possible to configure the how the device connects to the app, setting IP address or similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Navman So, the Vexilar SP200 is what you have? The info I'm finding online makes me think they botched the Wi-Fi implementation on that product. It looks like they chose to *not* give you a way to make it join an existing network. Vexilar may be sonar pros, but it seems like they're Wi-Fi noobs.